# How to identify installer type?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to uninstall applications silently. So how can i identify installer type (eg: Inno setup, NSIS, InstallShield, MSI etc ) in windows??
Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Comment: But, i Checked one of the application named "Silent install helper" they are fetching installer type..how it is possible ??

Comment: You can go through it...http://sourceforge.net/projects/sih/

Comment: If that project is open source, why can't *you* look and see how it works? As far as I know, you can't - in general - do this for **any** application.

Comment: Yes, but they have not given any source code...any way thank you very much..

Comment: If you come across any documents.. please let me know..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify software installers i.e,(Inno/NullSoft/installshield...etc.,) programmatically in mfc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986981/how-to-identify-software-installers-i-e-inno-nullsoft-installshield-etc-pr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look into source of SilentInstaller you will see PEiD, so they scan resources of executabiles.
Simple method - find keywords, like Inno Setup, Install Shield,... in executabile.
Hard method - each installer have it signature, like virus, I think it possible to calculate it, but taking too much time.
Hard method - find calculate offset of keywords of each installer.

some about, how find signature of inno setup : http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=86315